Не обновляется папка Downloads
Проблема проявляется на Windows 10 в браузерах Chrome и Firefox. Шаги воспроизведения:

Заранее открыть папку куда скачиваются файлы в Проводнике (Загрузки, Downloads).
Скачать какой-нибудь файл в браузере.
Открыть список загрузок в браузере и нажать кнопку Show in folder для последней загрузки.

Что происходит: ранее открытое окно с папкой Загрузки перемещается наверх. Но скачанного файла в нём нет - оно не обновилось. Если его обновить принудительно, то файл появится.
Что ожидается: если файл скачался, то он должен отобразиться в окне с папкой Загрузки.
Хотелось бы понять, это какая-то специфичная проблема, которая проявляется только у меня? Если только у меня, то отчего это может быть и как это можно исправить?
Если это проявляется у всех, то можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему? Я пишу расширение для браузера Chrome, которое скачивает файл и хочу, чтобы пользователь при нажатии на кнопку Show in folder видел скачанный файл.

Содержимое открытых в Проводнике папок должно обновляться автоматически. Возможно, в вашем случае этому что-то мешает — например, слишком большое число файлов или какие-то параметры отображения (но не уверен что конкретно может мешать)
